# How to make a PC behave as a router?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

as a lab assignment we are supposed to configure our linux pc with two network interfaces and make it behave as a router. could you give me some guidance on how to proceed?

Comment: Just toss in a Vyatta live CD :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will enable routing temporarily:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

If your want this option to survive a reboot, add `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to your `/etc/sysctl.conf`

HTH,
PEra

Comment: You'll also want each interface configured in different subnets

Comment: If you do that, what exactly is the effect?  An example?

Comment: Example? Use the IP of that box as gateway to the subnet on the other side of the router an it will forward your packets...

Comment: where do you configure the forward address?

Answer (score 2):

If it is just a simple packet forwarding, do what PEra suggested. Try looking up `shorewall` for a quick and easy way to configure more things. For more advanced information, refer to [LARTC](http://lartc.org) instead.

Comment: +1 for shorewall, though it does involve a bit of a learning curve, however the curve is MUCH less than diving straight into iptables.

Answer (score 0):

There is a large, detailed How-To [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~fenn/linux/). There is another good one [here](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/lanconnect/router/linux.htm).